# Ignore common name when verifiying certificate in openssl

Tags: c++, security, openssl

We are writing a new server/client app and need to Verify self-signed certificates in OpenSSL 1.1.0 where CN field isn't important.

I tried to do the following but it doesn't seem to have an effect:

```
X509_VERIFY_PARAM *param = NULL;
param = SSL_get0_param(sslo.ssl);
X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host(param, nullptr, 0);
```

How can I effectivly ignore all verification of this field?

**Update after Shane's answer:**

I tried setting verify_callback with SSL_CTX_set_verify .
In the callback I called X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth . The resulting error code was X509_V_ERR_DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT, which according to documentation means "the passed certificate is self signed and the same certificate cannot be found in the list of trusted certificates."

This error is very generic and not related specifically to CN, if I only change the CN field in the cert to appropriate value it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [SSL_CTX_set_verify](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html) call to specify your own verification callback function where you can OK anything you wish about the certificate.

Read that page carefully and it should tell you everything you need to know, the page also includes a example you can base your handler on if you wish.

Comment: I tried it, the problem is in that call back, when I call X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth
I get the error code: X509_V_ERR_DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
This a very generic error and is not specific to CN

Comment: It's telling you that the certificate presented is a self signed certificate.  By default it will not allow that.  If you want to allow that you can just override it in the callback function and just set the preverify_ok to 0 and return.  By doing this you will accept ANY self signed certificate so your security will be almost none as anyone can generate a self signed certificate and present it to your client.  You could check for a "specific" self signed certificate, it's up to you.  Just setting the preverify_ok to 0 and returning will accet ANY certificate in ANY state...

Comment: As I said, read that linked page carefully, it does tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Thanks Shane, I have already read that man page thorougly. Obviously I don't want a peer to present a random cert and be allowed to connect . I have a list a self-signed certs that I want to verify the peer cert against them but don't care about issuer or CN. How would I do that successfully?

Comment: If you are in "control" of the server(s), I would create my own CA certificate and then create the certificates the servers give out.  Then you can use a calist on your client with only your ca certificate.  That way you only trust the server when it's presenting a certificate with your ca that you control.

Comment: If you don't control the servers certificates, you can use certificate pinning.  Which just means you expect the server to to always provide the exact same certificate always.  This works but can be a configuration nightmare...  You may want to "prompt" the user the first time you see a certificate for a user to OK the server before saving it away as being the ok from that server from then onwards (like web browsers do for unknown certificates / untrusted certificates).

Comment: My situation is that the server doesn't generate the certificiates. It receives them from another app (over a secure channel) and is supposed to trust them. However the client will not necessarely present certificate that matches their hostname and so fail the verification. I control both client and server but not the app that provides the certificates. How do I prompt the client without risking a MITM attack? I'm of half a mind to just check the public key and be done with it.

Comment: You would be at risk of a MITM attack.  If you check the public key, what happens when the certificate is updated on the server?  You would have to update the client somehow with the new expected certificate.

Comment: Updating certs is not an issue. As I said both client and server are part of our product and are guaranteed to be always updated with the certs needed but not necessarily match the hostname